# My current job isn't a good fit, should I leave it off my resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume, applications

I've worked at this institution for less than two weeks and I know it's not a good fit for me. It has nothing to do with the people or anything, just professionally, I know it's not what I need, i'm 25 and not getting any younger.

I'm seeking other avenues of employment but I'm not sure if I should put this job on my resume or not. I was in my last position for 2 years and 5 months. My previous 2 jobs before that were 1 year 1 month and 1 year respectively. I'm a little conflicted because if I leave the current position off my most recent employment stops at just "June 2013 - November 2015", so, inevitably questions will come up either if I do that or if I am applying for a position with a resume that shows I've been at a job for less than a month.

My area of expertise is in IT. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I sure would.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

A past one of a few weeks I might be tempted to leave off, but your present one is not a good idea. Being unemployed is a red flag to some employers - after all, if you were that good, why hasn't someone else snapped you up? Having a job you want to bail from at two weeks is still a step up from no job; misfits do happen. And more importantly, you are digging a hole for yourself should an interviewer ask you what you are doing now; being seen to be less than upfront and honest could terminate your career when he checks your reference at your previous company and they tell a different story to your CV.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid being asked about your current job, so trying to hide it is only going to be problematic. Your situation is not that unusual. People often leave jobs because the job is no longer a good fit. It's a completely valid and honorable reason for leaving a job, so don't shy away from it. Just make sure you have a good explanation for why your job is not a good fit, and make sure you phrase it in a positive way. No whining!